# How to reenter the "main" morden network without removedb?

Tags: synchronization, morden

I synced geth using the `--fast` option, and after the sync, I had a little freak-out because I had lost all my ether.
Actually the problem is that although I have peers, I have not the good testnet blockchain.

I tested the following hashes :

```
> eth.getBlock(0).hash
"0x0cd786a2425d16f152c658316c423e6ce1181e15c3295826d7c9904cba9ce303"
> eth.getBlock(1000000).hash
"0x933de4c85a76c1b0652b01d4c22b5f66b76bd44005f607574900ab8bfd4ae052"
> eth.getBlock(1500000).hash
"0x92b43a22a1b33f69397d9fa4d54271df8217635c447f331690c8c21df53b3eab"
> eth.getBlock(1800000).hash
"0xb39e009518615dd1e792537aea755d9b83446a4c504a7df6facd48a8a9345213"
```

As you can see, my genesis block is correct, as well as the blocks 1000000 and 1500000, and the block 1800000 is wrong.

I tried the following command :
`for(i=0;i<admin.peers.length;i+=1) admin.removePeer(admin.peers[i].id)`

but geth doesn't resync its blockchain.

Where can I find peers for Morden?
Is there a different solution from doing removedb and sync again? I have no guarantee that it won't make a fork again!

Comment: So finally I did removedb, and am syncing using --fast, but this time without --cache=1024 --jitvm --jitcache=64. Hope this will work… I'll let you know!

Comment: Now I have the loop "gas used error" "Bad block #1873138" I had it on a previous server but I can't tell how I solved it

Comment: Re: gas used error: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that morden was running down